# Laravel 5.2 has many relationship - can't access fields

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

I have read the documentation about eloquent relationship and different articles online about it. but it seems I'm getting a hard time accessing the fields for my table's relationship. Please advice.

`User->hasMany BuyRequest`

**User table** columns:

```
id,
userid (int),
name
```

**BuyRequest table** columns:

```
id,
buyrequest_id,
userid (int)
```

Here code of my User Model,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\BuyRequest;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','userid',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function buyRequest(){
        return $this->hasMany(BuyRequest::class,'userid','userid');
    }

}
```

code of my buyRequest Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
class BuyRequest extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'buyrequest';

    protected $fillable = [
        'buyrequest_id'
    ];

}
```

Controller class where I'm accessing the variable

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductPostRequest;
use App\Products;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\BuyRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\RFQRequest;
use App\ProductCategory;

class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function show(Request $request){

        $user = new User();
        $buyrequest = $user->buyRequest();

        dump($buyrequest->getResults());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Collection {#241 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

I have zero items on my collection, am I accessing the buyrequest properly? please help.

I already tried the one in laravel documentation, please see below.

```
$buyrequest1 = User::find(1)->buyrequest;

        foreach ($buyrequest1 as $br) {
            dump($br->title);
        }
```

and I get this output:

Trying to get property of non-object

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a day. I think I found what I'm looking for. Thank you for @Nadimul De Cj for helping me experiment with other options and helping me solve it.

Basically before you can access a buyrequest of user you should filter first who's buyrequest access you want to output.

okay another explanation, select first the user that you want to access the buyrequest by using where statement..... so, user where id is equal to 1 then access his buy request. we can't just use the user model then directly access the buyrequest model, or we can say that's not practical to do.

here's the code.

```
$user = User::where('userid','1')->firstOrFail();
        dump($user->buyrequest['0']->title);
```

output:
"Cold Pyro Indoor Show Crackers"

here's my relationship code.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\BuyRequest;
class User extends Authenticatable
{

 public function buyRequest(){
        return $this->hasMany(BuyRequest::class,'userid','userid');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your  BuyRequest Model add the column name userid like below:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\BuyRequest;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'email', 'password','userid',
   ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function buyRequest(){
        return $this->hasMany(BuyRequest::class,'userid','userid');
    }

}
```

And access it as like below:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function show(Request $request){

        $user = User::with('buyRequest')->where('userid','1')->firstOrFail();

        dump($user[0]->buyRequest[0]->title);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I just tried it and still can't access any fields, I still have zero total collections.

Comment: can you please add belongsTo or  belongsToMany instead of hasMany in User model class /// like:---     public function buyRequest(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BuyRequest::class,'userid','userid');
    }

Comment: I tried the belongsTo and I still have zero total collections, for the belongsToMany, the result is ...

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'heroku_7775a568a08e5ba.userid' doesn't exist (SQL: select `buyrequest`.*, `userid`.`userid` as `pivot_userid`, `userid`.`buy_request_id` as `pivot_buy_request_id` from `buyrequest` inner join `userid` on `buyrequest`.`id` = `userid`.`buy_request_id` where `userid`.`userid` is null)

Comment: my code is  public function buyRequest(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(BuyRequest::class,'userid','userid');
    }

Comment: Hi, I tried you answer and here's the result. 

BelongsTo {#230 ▼
  #foreignKey: "userid"
  #otherKey: "userid"
  #relation: "user"
  #query: Builder {#238 ▶}
  #parent: BuyRequest {#236 ▶}
  #related: User {#229 ▶}
}. How can I access the User fields? .. btw, the answer I think is the inverse of what I want to achieve. I want to access all buyRequest fields from the User model. I'm going to review my code again and post my updates today.

Comment: try this      $user = User::with('buyRequest')->get();
        print_r($user[0]->buyRequest); what is the output ??

Comment: Hi I tried it, here's the output. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\BuyRequest Object ( [table:protected] => buyrequest [primaryKey:protected] => buyrequest_id [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => buyrequest_id [1] => userid ) [connection:protected] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [buyrequest_id] => sdfdsfsdavdvadvasdvsdfafsdaf [title] => Cold Pyro Indoor Show Crackers [estquantity] => 6 [unit] => Nos .......

Comment: I tried this code, $user = User::where('userid','1')->firstOrFail();
        
        foreach($user->buyrequest as $u){
            $k = $u->buyrequest;
            dump($k);
        }, but I cant null values, am I accessing the buyrequest correctly?